# Scala implicit function

Tags: scala

I am trying following code in Scala.

```scala
implicit def str2Int(x:String):Int = x.toInt
```

But I am getting error

```
Solution.scala:37: error: type mismatch;
 found   : x.type (with underlying type String)
 required: ?{def toInt: ?}

Note that implicit conversions are not applicable because they are ambiguous:
 both method augmentString in object Predef of type (x: String): scala.collection.StringOps
 and method str2Int in object Result of type (x: String): Int
 are possible conversion functions from x.type to ?{def toInt: ?}
    implicit def str2Int(x:String):Int = x.toInt
                                         ^
Solution.scala:37: error: value toInt is not a member of String
    implicit def str2Int(x:String):Int = x.toInt
```

I don't know what is wrong here. Please suggest.

Comment: The **String** class doesn't have any `toInt` method, it is added as an extension method. However, since extension methods are implicit conversions under the hood yours is creating an ambiguity. - My advice, stay away from pure implicit conversions, they are dangerous, use extension methods instead.

Comment: I have agreed with @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez. you should avoid pure implicit conversions. But if you desperately want to do this just use Integer.parseInt("3") instead of toInt because toInt is also doing same under the hood.